# C++ fgetws() returns wide string with one space inbetween every character

Tags: c++

I want to read a **UTF 16 LE** file. This file is about > 300 MB and I am gonna read it chunk by chunk using `fgetws()`.

But when looping through the file, I see **one extra space** after every character. How am I going to fix this without creating an inefficiency in my code?

Here is some sample code:

```
#define MAX_CHUNK 4096

int main(){


  /* My utf16 file I want to read */
  FILE* myfile = fopen("UTFsixteen.txt","r");

  /* Skip bom */
  fseek(myfile,3,SEEK_CUR);

  /* The chunk that I am going to extract and read character by character */
  wchar_t chunk[MAX_CHUNK] = "";

  /* Loop over the file chunk by chunk */
  for(;fgetws(chunk,MAX_CHUNK,myfile) != NULL;){

     /* Obtain the start of the chunk */
     wchar_t* start_of_chunk = chunk;
     wchar_t* current_chunk_character = start_of_chunk;
          
     /* Loop over every character in the chunk 
      * After every character one extra space occurres */
     for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CHUNK; current_chunk_character++,i++){

        /* Processing over here */
        
     }

  }
 
}
```

The contents of the file `UTFsixteen.txt` through notepad :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet cursus sit
amet dictum sit amet justo. Enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus
metus. Enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam.
Porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Viverra
suspendisse potenti nullam ac. Tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in
ante.

(This is repeated over 1 million times)
```

Comment: No UTF16LE encoded file is going to have a three byte BOM. You (or whoever wrote the file) is getting confused with UTF8.

Comment: To read wide characters from a C stream, you have to use the [fwide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwide) function after opening and prior to the first read.

Comment: Finally there is no guarantee that `wchar_t` is 16 bits. It might be, but that is platform dependent. In practise you are better off reading bytes and doing any necessary translations yourself.

Comment: whats the difference between `fgetws()` and `fwide()` ?

Comment: fgetws read characters, fwide sets the stream mode. You have to use fwide **before** you use fgetws.

Comment: Oh okay thanks ! Also please consider upvoting if you want to :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, @john said that :

> To read wide characters from a C stream, you have to use the fwide function
> after opening and prior to the first read.

Before you start reading using fgetws() you must call fwide() so that the input is read properly